# How to write simple code in LInq

Tags: c#

I have the following in my NotSelectedList.

```
public List<TestModel> SelectedList = new List<TestModel>();
public List<TestModel>NotSelectedList =  new List<TestModel>();
NotificationDetailsModel projects = new NotificationDetailsModel();
projects.ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(Row["ProjectID"]);
projects.Valid= Convert.ToBoolean(Row["Validity"]);
NotSelectedList.Add(projects);
```

How can I write a simple code in LINQ to select from the NotSelectedList where Validity == True and store the data in SelectedList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var results = NotSelectedList.Where(x => x.Valid);
foreach (var item in results)
    SelectList.Add(item);
```

Although for performance reasons you may be better off doing something like this:

```
foreach (var item in NotSelectedList)
{
    if (item.Valid)
        SelectList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: In the first line, the return value of where is not the results of the query but a query object. The variable name `results` is a misleading name.

Comment: @RCIX: the `NotSelectedList.Where(x => x.Valid);` is completely valid LINQ syntax.

Comment: @MarkByers: you might be right, when I originally wrote it I had a ToList() on the end but in the end decided to drop it. I forgot to rename it... I can adjust it if you think it will make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
var query = from ns in NotSelectedList
            from n in SelectedList
            where ns.Valid && ns.ProjectID == n.ProjectID
            select ns;
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

The following would select the items with Validity = true from NotSelectedList and place them in SelectedList:

```
SelectedList.AddRange(NotSelectedList.Where(item => item.Validity));
```